# Maatwebsite Excel can't bypass empty row on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using Laravel 4 and Maatwebsite Laravel Excel to import form CSV files.
I managed to import each rows in the csv file successfully.
How ever, when it comes to empty files, the site returns: Row 2 is out of range (2 - 1).
Here is my code:

```
                    Excel::load($source, function($reader) {
                    $reader->all(); 
                })
```

Is there any way to bypass empty row or to verify row count before process?

Comment: Finally, after reading the vendor codes, just found this method
    getTotalRowsOfFile()
Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to get row count. Then manipulate it.

```
->getTotalRowsOfFile()
```